# PHP MySQLi query - "Permission denied"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im using PHP MySQLi to connect to MySQL and sometimes doing query i get error:

> "Permission denied" error code: 2002.

The strange thing is that it happens for different query's and totally unpredictable. For example it might happen on third query after first two executed correctly.

I know it is not problem with MySQL because i moved it from one server to another and problem still persists. Most likely problem with PHP or interconnection between PHP and MySQL servers (they're on different machines)

Anyone got ideas?

EDIT:
query what gets "Permission denied" works if i restart script - its not permissions problem

ERROR:

> [23-Apr-2011 19:00:02] PHP Warning: 
>   mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]:
>   [2002] Permission denied (trying to
>   connect via
>   tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306) in
>   /home/.../DB.php on line 19
>   [23-Apr-2011 19:00:02] PHP Warning: 
>   mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]:
>   (HY000/2002): Permission denied in
>   /home/.../DB.php on line 19

Comment: Put *complete* error message here please.

Comment: Could it be timing out, or a ddos protection?

Comment: but if it would be about timing out wouldn't i get "timed out" error?

Comment: Refer to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock">this thread</a>. I had the same problem but this thread solved it for me.

Comment: I'm aware that the duplicate is newer than this question, but the answer there provides a far better approach to SELinux interference with database connections than just disabling it.

Answer (score 20):

Same things happened on my environment. And the cause was SELinux.

You might be able to connect the database by executing php from command line
while you might not by executing on the web server.

In my case, I turned off SELinux.

```
# setenforce 0
```

Or you have to set up SELinux correctly.

Comment: I always forget SELinux on a new server install and it always interrupts the work-flow somehow. Thanks for the reminder allowing me to move on.

Comment: For ideas on how to set SELinux up correctly see accepted answer for: https://serverfault.com/questions/240015/how-do-i-allow-mysql-connections-through-selinux

Answer (score 0):

I think the database user do not have sufficient permission to make particular operation on particular mysql table.

Comment: but if no permissions i wouldn't be able to run other query's. And same query works just fine other times.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a permissions error. The client isn't able to get as far as connecting to the database, let alone trying to authenticate the user.

I suspect these problems will be being caused by either network problems (preventing the client/server machines from talking to each other) or the MySQL server process not running on the remote host.

The error code is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Answer (score -1):

Check The Permissions for the user that you are connected through