# For what reason would mysql deny access to a specific computer on a wildcard host?

Tags: php, database, permissions, mysqli

In my mysql database, I have a user 'developer'@'%'.  My developers are each connecting to the database as this user using PHP scripts and the `new mysqli()` command remotely from their own machines.  I just installed fedora 19 on brand new computer for another developer, and got their localhost up and running, but for whatever reason, when they load the PHP scripts onto their localhost and try to connect to the remote database using the exact same credentials as every other computer every other developer is using, this error is returned

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied in /var/www/html/core/inc/ism.global.helper.php on line 82
```

I've tried opening the firewall on this local machine to allow the outgoing connection, re-installing httpd, and even adding another user 'developer'@'ip-address' where 'ip-address' is the specific IP address of this new machine, still getting the same error. I've also tried setting the database host in the mysqli() parameter as the direct IP address to the server instead of the domain name. Same error. Any ideas as to why access would be denied just for this one computer?

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock ? could this be a ipv4/ipv6 incompatibility issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that the mysql.so and mysqli.so modules needed to be loaded. I added:

```
extension=mysql.so
```

and

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

to their respective mysql.ini and mysqli.ini files in /etc/php.d and restarted httpd.

The connection worked fine after that.