# Can't connect to mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using the following to connect to MySQL

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', 'chat');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo mysqli_connect_error($con);
        die;
    }
?>
```

But, I'm given the following error

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

I've never run into this error before and I have no idea what it means. I'm able to connect my DB via PHPMyAdmin and an SQL desktop client.

Comment: Are you sure you are using 127.0.0.1 in PHPMyAdmin too?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions provided in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13769504/2903251

Comment: @GolezTrol Yep, it just came to mind that he probably isn't the first person with this question ;)