# Joomla 3.3.4 Database configuration error

Tags: joomla, wamp

I am using WampServer and I am trying to install Joomla 3.3.4 on my localhost.

In section Database Configuration I get the error

```
Could not connect to the database. Connector returned number: Could not connect to MySQL."
```

I try to leave password blank, but still it doesnt connect.

P.S.Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you following the Installation instructions. They are simple to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use "root" as username.
- Use an empty password.
- Use "joomla" as database name.

Answer (score 1):

The error speaks for itself.

You're getting this because you have either typed in an incorrect:

1. Database name
2. Database username
3. Database password

Either that, or you have not assigned the username you created in PHPmyAdmin to the actual database.

Comment: i checked all things you wrote, but still got same error

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if MYSQL is running? 
When Mysql service is stopped then this error normally occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing **localhost** by **127.0.0.1** solved the problem for me.

I got the idea reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock).