# php cron job command cannot connect to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm trying to execute a php file using cron job(cPanel) with a parameter

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/user/public_html/en/videos/includes/converter.php abc123
```

when I run "**converter.php**" through http/exec the mysql connection is working fine

but when I run with cron job, I'm getting this:

**Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket**

my question is: why when using php exec I'm being able to connect to the DB but when using the cron jobs I can't?

Comment: Which user are you running that crontab as? Can you post the connection  info (minus password)? Also, have you confirmed that '/usr/bin/php' is the same one your server is using?

Comment: the db connection is fine, and I'm using my username they provide to me... Also the php file is being executed by cron job but so it's working if there was not mysql connections in it

Comment: Got it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock