# Running PHP5: access denied to MySQLi connection but success for MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I ran this code to get the output shown in image below:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

[image]

Trouble is, I cannot figure out why this works:

```
$conn = @mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
      @mysql_select_db('dbName') or die(mysql_error());

      $query="SELECT * FROM Clients";

     $result = @mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
      if ($result)
      {
            $outp = "";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      {

        if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
        $outp .= '{"ClientID":"'  . $row["cID"] . '",';
        $outp .= '"ClientsName":"'   . $row["clientsName"] . '"}'; 
      }
      mysql_free_result($result);
      }
    $outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
    echo($outp);
```

But this does not:

```
$conn = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "dbName");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Clients");

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"ClientID":"'  . $rs["cID"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"ClientsName":"'   . $rs["clientsName"] . '"}'; 
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();

echo($outp);
```

The error that I get is:

> Connection failed: Access denied for user 'user'@'host' to database 'dbName'

I read that as long as PHP5 is running, MySQLi is also already installed. What else might I need to check for? Maybe I am doing something wrong in my code? This is my first attempt at MySQLi, I haven't connected to a database in years, had to rummage through old code just to get the old SQL way to connect to database.

Comment: Are you running both scripts on the same machine?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. One file, I just changed the script (comment one out, run other). So on same host, etc.

Comment: Then I can't think of any good reason why the new one would fail like this. Double check for typos.

Comment: In your `phpinfo` do you have a `mysqli` block? Do you also have a `mysqlnd` block? Also, what kind of server? (CentOS, Ubuntu, Windows, etc)

Comment: run `phpinfo()` on the server and make sure they have mysqli configured to be on (though that probably is not the issue).  Also check your connection file;  make sure the variable names are defined correctly

Comment: did you get valid output in scenario 1? or just no errors?

Comment: @Machavity Linux. There is a table in the phpinfo() for mysqli running version 5. Didn't see anything about block.

Comment: have you tried the `mysqli` without specifying a dbName?

Comment: @fbas valid output in scenario 1. I am able to move forward with my project, I would just rather connect to the database via mysqli.

Comment: @Christine268 Do you have access to the command line of this server?

Comment: @chiliNUT I did not put actual names for the host, user, pass, or dbName in my question, naturally. But I have actual names for them in my php, naturally. The same ones are being used in mysqli connection that doesn't work as the mysql connection that doesn't work.

Comment: @Machivity I do not. It is on a host website.

Comment: @Christine268 In the `mysqli` block what is the client API version?

Comment: @Christine268 I just mean, like, connect to mysqli without specifying the dbname, and run a query like "select * from dbName.tablename" and see if that yields a different result

Comment: @Machivity 5.5.42-37.1

Comment: @chiliNUT you are onto something. I got it to say "Connected successfully" from my echo! So we have connection now. :) Only strange thing now is the echo($outp); isn't echoing.

Comment: The `$outp` variable is coming from the database.  In other words, you successfully connected to the server, but for some reason aren't connecting to the database.   verify the database name, or add the database name to your query, such as `SELECT * FROM dbname.Clients`   (note,  case sensitivity matters)

Comment: Nice! So my suggestion from before was based on the user somehow not having permission to connect to that db, while still having permission to connect to the server. why that would be different for mysqli vs mysql, however, I do not know. are you connecting to localhost? maybe this tangentially related SO could be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock

Comment: @chilliNUT interesting. Yea I have no idea why it would differentiate, and yes, I am connecting to localhost, as I have always done. The user I am using has full permissions, so I haven't a clue why I wouldn't have permission to database..let alone permission with mysql but not with mysqli. I took a look at that link, unfortunately I am not so good with the technical side of things. But I suppose I could try those steps that are given in the answer and see if they do anything for me.

Comment: You may see this article for your issue.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes

Comment: Just throwing this in...are you specifying a port for mysqli?  Probably not it if you are connecting to the server ok.  However you can have users that are user@localhost  or user@127.0.0.1 so check the address is the same and that the correct port is being passed.

Comment: Try `SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user;` . Make sure your user information is what it's supposed to be. Otherwise, just make sure mysqli is enabled. Head scratcher. Let me know how it goes. Remember, on Linux the database names (actually directories on the filesystem) will be case sensitive.

Comment: For that matter, do `SHOW DATABASES` to check the names of your databases. Seems like that "user" does not have privileges to access the database? Odd, especially if it works with the mysql functions.

Comment: My last idea, try `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'hostname';`, where hostname is localhost or some other host's name.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly fine.

Make sure there are no typos in the auth details.

Secondly, MySQL users are binded to hosts. For example `root@localhost`. If you're connecting from a remote host, make sure you have set up a user like `root@123.123.123.123` or allow all hosts by using the % wildcard like `root@%`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A while back I bumped into a sql client challenge where the version of php caused the client to refuse to connect to the server in mysqli for an arcane security reason. To resolve the issue, I had to turn on logging for mysql (debug logging) and check the debug log on the server after an attempt. Your problem sounds very familiar and may even be the same one. It required altering the password type if I recall correctly.