# mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, failed-installation

### Installation of Apache, PHP, MySQL, phpMyAdmin sends errors when trying to login

I have been trying to configure this web server package on a mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 but unfortunately I have not succeed yet.

I followed a tutorial from:  https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/
but after everything was finished (before the permissions section) I tried to go to http://localhost/~username/phpmyadmin/ and after entering the **right** user and password I was unable to log in, and error messages came up.

I have tried to install everything again, using this video-tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2Qt1H4duYw but again I wasn't able to log in, and the same error messages came up.

Now, I am not even sure if it would be a good idea to start over again the installation, since I am not good with the console I just follow the directions, but I am afraid that I may be playing around too much, and even making it worse!

This are the messages it sends me when I try to log in:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

I have been researching about this errors, and what I could get was that they are a bug...? but I also realized that many people look for a solution, but we all leave the sites without it.

Any idea about how to fix this bug?

---

**UPDATE:**
I have just found some help reading another question, and I tried editing the *php.ini.default*, according to what Vijay's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43628005/10108245) on this post just I am not able to (I don't know how to) update the settings for PORT/SOCKET-PATH etc to make it connect to the server.

**Note:** I do not have a my.cnf file, so I have not been able to use the answer suggested by this link