# Can't connect to local MySQL that was working

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I just finished a website and wanted to backup tonight but I suddenly got:

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

database is refusing to connect, what can I do?
Anyone has previous experience with this issue?
Is there a way to fix it without loosing my data?

Comment: hope this give help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock/13771199

Comment: Make sure your /tmp directory has the permissions of 1777 (777).