# mysql permission denied from browser; but works from cli

Tags: php, mysql

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else {
echo "success";
}
```

when I am running this code on cli, I get the success message.

When I try this code from the browser, i.e run the index.php, I get `permission denied` error.

This is the VPS where I am doing it.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: [This looks like the same problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769220/php-mysqli-query-permission-denied)

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your php file does not have enough rights to be executed try changing its rights with chmod

From the `chmod` man pages:

> The chmod utility modifies the file mode bits of the listed files as
>   specified by the mode operand. It may also be used to modify the
>   Access Control Lists (ACLs) associated with the listed files.

```
SYNOPSIS
     chmod [-fv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] mode file ...
     chmod [-fv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a] ACE file ...
     chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E] file ...
     chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-C] file ...
     chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-N] file ...
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense because the code runs correctly from the cli without getting a `permission denied` error.